# Compiling only part of a library on iOS

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I have a big library on iOS which is using a lot of other libraries.

It started well, but after a while I realised that sometimes I only need part of it for my project. And since the whole thing is pretty big I would like to make a sub-library that is only the selected classes + selected embeded libraries that I'd chose for a particular project.

For example:

My project has files a.m to z.m, and they all use independently libraries a.a to z.a

And I would like to compile b,c,j and r classes/lib to make my library.

I started reading about cocoa pods which should help, but I thought there would be other solutions. Is that possible and easy to do in another way?

Comment: How about refactoring each small lib to its own target within the project? This will give you the ability to only build a specific target lib.

Comment: I thought about that, but it makes it impossible to combine any way I might need.

Doing this would require a target for a+b, one for a+c, one for a+b+c etc... and if I want to add anything after the last one... :)